# No result when fetching the most common entry in a field

Tags: php, mysql

i feel as dumb as a door knob. Could i get some advice as to why i do not get a result returned here. Please be so kind as to put me out of my missery.

```
$query = mysql_query
(
   "SELECT first_name, 
           COUNT(first_name) AS answer
    FROM orders 
    GROUP BY first_name 
    ORDER BY answer DESC
    LIMIT 1"
); 

echo "<p>The most frequent customer is $result</p>";
```

Comment: Please upgrade your PHP scripts to use mysqli/PDO. mysql is deprecated, unmaintained and will be removed from future PHP versions.

Comment: this is ur full code or are u missing something?

Comment: please give full code of running the query

Comment: yes please avoid using `mysql_` use PDO here is the [link] (php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @knittl, "upgrading" mysql-lib does not help with his problem. And he will get serious problems if he "upgrade" to mysqli and uses PHP 4, or if PDO and using less than PHP 5.1. Mysql_* is deprecated in newer versions, but is **not** inapplicable, and does the job perfectly - but _may_ be removed in a future version, lets say about 5 years-

Answer (score 1):

Check this..

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, COUNT(first_name) AS answer 
FROM orders 
GROUP BY first_name 
ORDER BY answer DESC
LIMIT 1"); 

$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo "<p>The most frequent customer is " . $result["first_name"] . "</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, COUNT(first_name) AS answer FROM orders GROUP BY first_name ORDER BY answer DESC LIMIT 1");
$array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "<p>The most frequent customer is ".$array[0]['first_name']."</p>";
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone who took the time to reply. I see now that i needed the $array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) if i were a chick i would be blonde! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the call to `mysql_fetch_array()` after having executed the query. A query could also be an `INSERT` operation or similar. It only returns information about the request itself (e.g. was it successful, is a result attached to it?), but not the information itself.

This has to do with the database itself: Information is returned as a so called cursor which you can iterate as needed. Thus, not all results have to be saved in memory at one time. E.g. you could not have only one result as in your case, but a million rows. At some point this could be too much for your memory. Then, cursor and row-wise iteration help a lot.

So, you need to call:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, COUNT(first_name) AS answer 
FROM orders 
GROUP BY first_name 
ORDER BY answer DESC
LIMIT 1");

$result = mysql_fetch_array($query); // will retrieve the first row from the result
// if you have multiple rows (not LIMIT 1), you would have to call it again and again

echo "<p>The most frequent customer is $result['first_name']</p>";
```